# Splitview Control navigating views

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am working with the SplitViewController for the iPad for the first time and trying to convert me iPhone app to run on the iPad. I have a couple of cells in a section such as Name, Phone Number etc in a navigation controller that i would like to adapt to work with the split view. I essentially would like the User to view the fields they can enter on the masterview of the splitview and when they tap a cell, the corresponding view should appear in the details view on the right. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay at doing some self-learning, I would suggest simply creating a Master-Detail application in XCode.  IMO that has a pretty nice template of how to set up the master and view controllers in a split view, and it will properly set up your details controller to handle hiding the master when going portrait.

In your code where (I'm guessing) you push a new view on in the iPhone version, you should just check the device type (or if `self.splitViewController` is set), and instead of pushing a new view on, modify the detail.  The detail view controller will always be set to `[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 1]`

If you want more fine-grain control over your split view controller (showing the Master View as part of the SplitView when in portrait, or hiding the Master in landscape as well), I'd recommend using the excellent [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) on github